# Recycle Bin shows all deleted items

Tags: configuration

In Recycle Bin, the user (not super admin) can see all deleted items by other users. It should be shown only deleted items by him/her. (I guess it is already sitecore's default setting)

The user has general member of default sitecore roles and there is no special events regarding this Recycle Bin.

Do you have any idea about how I can figure out?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bug in the current version of Sitecore (8.2). You can contact Sitecore Support with the reference number 127149 and get a patch that fixes this.

This happens when users are not in the **sitecore** domain.

The bug exists in `Sitecore.Data.Archiving.SqlArchive` in `Sitecore.Kernel`. The issue is in the `GetEntryCount(User)` method which does not have a check on the `Recycly Bin/Can See All Items` policy.

The `sitecore\Everyone` role is denied access to the policy, but users with another domain than **sitecore** is not a member of this role and can therefore see all items.

Comment: Thanks, now I'm using v8.0 (151127) and I don't know if there bug was from this version. Let me try first. Thx!!!

Comment: I think it might have been there since 8.0, but I'm not 100% sure on that.